# Why does printing a data frame assume another encoding than printing a column of the data frame?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I create a data frame with `ä` encoded in UTF-8:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = c('\xc3\xa4'));
> df$a <- as.character(df$a);
```

As of yet, the encoding of `df$a` is unknown, as expected:

```
> Encoding(df$a);
[1] "unknown"
```

When printing `df$a`, it prints garbage which I sort of expected, too:

```
> df$a;
[1] "Ã¤"
```

So, I explicitely set the encoding of `df$a` to UTF-8:

```
> Encoding(df$a) <- 'UTF-8';
```

Printing `df$a` now gives me the correct character:

```
> df$a;
[1] "ä"
```

However, when I print the entire data set, I get something unexpected again.

```
> df
         a
1 <U+00E4>
```

Although `df$a` does not have a zero-byte anywhere:

```
> charToRaw(df$a)
[1] c3 a4
```

I am failing to understand why printing `df` behaves differently than printing `df$a`.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue.